# Use SAP Connector for .NET in VB6

Tags: vb6, sap-dotnet-connector

Is it possible to use the SAP Connector for .NET  in VB6 respectively can be used as COM-Component (COM-visible) or is it better to write a COM-visible wrapper, which hides everything of the connector ?

I must access from an old vb6 application to SAP and don't want to use the SAP DCOM Connector.

Comment: Alternatively, you could lie and say that it's not possible. That would hasten the demise of the old vb6 app. Adding new features to VB6 applications is foolish, to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a wrapper in Visual Studio 2003 and make it COM-visible... I wrote once a wrapper on the RFC library that was COM-visible and some people used it with VB and VBScript. Unfortunately I do not have access to this wrapper anymore as I changed my employment.